# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES on OS X Mountain Lion after Java Critical Update

Tags: java, android, macos, certificate

Yesterday I update the java SE in OS X with those

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10-428-11M3811)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01-428, mixed mode)
```

The ADT stop compiling my app, nothing else changed, reading a lot seems that this upgrade was the problem, one of the most important think its that i didn't find how to downgrade the java version o fix this issue, can't update to the java SE 7 because Android its based on java SE 6 (more accurately on Apache Harmony that doesn't support completely java SE 6).

There its another way to fix it?

```
Im using OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.1
Java SE 6 "1.6.0_35-b10-428-11M3811"
Eclipse 4.2.0
ADT 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
```

In the LogCat I get

```
Package com.xxx.xxx has no certificates at entry res/drawable/close.png; ignoring!
```

And the thing its that the proyect doesnt have such file, so i'm assuming that its an drawable of the Android SDK itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was some libs that seems was conflicting with this java version, in this case was all the library commons-io and commons-lang3 from the org.apache, when removed the innecesary files from there I was able to compile it.

The exact console log was

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: templates/release-notes.vm
Origin 1: path_to_project/libs/commons-lang3-3.1-sources.jar
Origin 2: path_to_project/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
```

There was 2 errors, when removed those files I was hable to run it, when I try to reproduce it i just get the duplicate file for APK, seems that after the instalation the keystore was cleaned or something like that and this specific error stop the compilation and signing of the apk.